# Error parsing XAML: "Integer types not allowed" errors for many attributes such as width

Tags: c#, android, xml, compiler-errors, xamarin.android

So, I'm a new Xamarin developer and got stuck with something very basic. The compiler gives an error at `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` line. The error is `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

I have tried adding all of these in the root element (Linear Layout in my case) but it doesn't work:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Here's the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/loginbgandbtnldpi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/LoginBGImgView" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LoginEmailEditText"
            android:width="300"
            android:layout_marginTop="295"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30"
            android:text="Email"
            app:paddingStart="20"
            android:paddingLeft="35"/>
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LoginPassEditText"
            android:text="Password"
            android:width="300"
            android:paddingLeft="35"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30"
            android:layout_marginTop="348" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="432"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100"
            android:width="160"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
`Error Parsing XML: unbound prefix` solved by removing `app:paddingStart="20"`
Updated Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/loginbgandbtnldpi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/LoginBGImgView" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LoginEmailEditText"
            android:width="300"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30"
            android:text="Email"
            android:paddingLeft="35"
            android:layout_marginRight="30"
            android:layout_marginTop="295" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LoginPassEditText"
            android:text="Password"
            android:width="300"
            android:paddingLeft="35"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30"
            android:layout_marginTop="348"
            android:layout_marginRight="30" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="432"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100"
            android:width="160"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

New errors list:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value '100').    
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value '30'). 
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value '30'). 
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginRight' with value '30').    
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginRight' with value '30').    
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '295'). 
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '348'). 
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '432').     
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'paddingLeft' with value '35').
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'paddingLeft' with value '35').
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'width' with value '160').
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'width' with value '300').
Error       Integer types not allowed (at 'width' with value '300').
```

**EDIT 2:**
Issue resolved by specifying 'dp' with the integer values.

Comment: The xml is not valid.  You need to define the namespace "app" with an attribute like "android" is defined on line 2 of the xml.

Comment: Or possibly you want `android:paddingStart="20"` instead of `app:paddingStart="20"`.  You can use https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to find XML errors like this one.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your comment, it solved the problem but other error arose where I have specified and integer value for property `android:width="300"`
Now there error is `"Integer types not allowed at ('wdith' with value '300')`

Comment: @HammadNasir its because you need to give a unit, just `300` wont do:
`android:width="300dp"` (not sure if dp works on xamarin)

Comment: @dbc it would solve the problem but it is not the answer to the question in title so I guess not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Support different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) from android's document.

To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different densities, you must design your UI using *density-independent pixels* (`dp`) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.

For example, when you specify spacing between two views, use `dp`:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/clickme"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

When defining text sizes, however, you should instead use *scalable pixels* (`sp`) as your units (but never use sp for layout sizes). The sp unit is the same size as dp, by default, but it resizes based on the user's preferred text size.

When specifying text size, always use `sp`:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**So** here solution should add `dp` for layout in **axml**.

Answer (score 1):

Use SP for Text size (Scale independent pixel)
and DP for Everything else(Density independent pixel)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to post the answer I gave in comments:

its because you need to give a unit, just 300 wont do: android:width="300dp"